# script to group random range directories in a given order using shell script

Tags: shell-script, rhel

1) I have directories from 0 to 3120203 (note directories are not in sequence they are random)

```
-bash-4.1$ ls
0        1261826  211205   2398339  267475   295482   339902  395546  457254  503959  538784  583032  643106  78093   906653
1000791  126359   211250   2398362  267592   295488   340070  39565   457378  504052  538846  583103  643168  78143   91594
1001022  126944   2114355  2398373  267667   29583    341088  395652  457471  504160  540470  583316  64447   781579  91777
1002557  127163   2129010  2398380  267771   2959608  341300  395786  457628  504219  540632  583875  645373  782220  921760
1004183  127316   2129165  2398388  268076   296331   341452  396207  457758  504278  541300  583998  645437  78227   924976
1004399  127416   2132965  2398396  2681923  296456   341512  39720   457820  504337  541754  584219  645816  782272  925382
1005369  130416   2137199  2398482  268333   2964801  341688  39779   457879  504404  541994  584278  645876  782704  928134
```

2) I want to sort and group all those directories and move it under specific range of 50000.

eg: directories from  0 to 50000 should move under 50000, 50001 to 100000 move under 100000 and so on. iterations should be of 50000

I am not expert on shell scripting:

here is my shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#set -x
#Please pass document library path
SOURCE=/opt/dms/
DEST=/opt/nes_dms
cd $SOURCE
ls | sort -n >> /opt/ncm/list.txt
for dir in `cat /opt/ncm/list.txt`
do
#echo $dir
if [ "$dir" -le "50000" ]
then
echo $dir is less then $i
mv $dir $DEST
fi
done
```

I need the script to be incremented automatically by 50000+50000=100000 and move all directories between 50001 to 100000 in 100000 dir till we read all dir in a file.

Comment: Do not use shreenshots; paste the output as code instead. Not all of it, just enough to get the picture.

Comment: @HaukeLaging removed screenshot and updated with the output of ls command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
#set -x
#Please pass document library path
SOURCE='/crypto/home/hl/tmp/stackexchange/dir_groups/source'
DEST='/crypto/home/hl/tmp/stackexchange/dir_groups/target'
declare -a target_dir_indexes
cd "$SOURCE" || exit 1
for dir in *; do
    test "$DEBUG" = 'yes' && echo "$dir"
    test -d "$dir" && ! test -L "$dir" || continue
    if ! [[ "$dir" =~ ^(0|[1-9][0-9]*)$ ]]; then
        echo "error: dir name '${dir}'; skipping"
        continue
    fi
    target_index=$((dir/50000))
    if [ "$dir" -gt 0 ]; then
        if [ $((dir%50000)) -eq 0 ]; then
            ((target_index--))
        fi
    fi
    target_dir_name=$(((target_index+1)*50000))
    target_dir_path="${DEST}/${target_dir_name}"
    # avoid unneccessary calls to mkdir or the VFS
    if [ -z "${target_dir_indexes[target_index]}" ]; then
        mkdir -p "$target_dir_path"
        target_dir_indexes[target_index]=1
    fi
    echo "${dir} is moved to ${target_dir_name}"
    mv -i "$dir" "$target_dir_path"
done
```

Comment: 0 dir in $SOURCE is getting skipped to be moved in $target_dir_path

Comment: @NitinMestry Oh, there actually is a `0` entry, I should have had a closer look at the list... I have adapted the regex to include `0`.

Comment: @isaac I already noticed that when reading your answer and fixed it.

Comment: @NitinMestry I have made another modification because the border numbers (n*50000) were put in the wrong group.

Comment: need your help on modifying the script:

With this script mail gloal is achieved to move given range of directories, now 2nd thing i want is if we rerun the script it should only move modified contents in source under destination directory. which should take less time as we are just moving only modified directories.

Answer (score 1):

**WARN:** script bellow doesn't handle errors when directory is not numeric named.

Posible solution:

```
#!/bin/bash
#set -x

SOURCE=/opt/dms/
DEST=/opt/nes_dms

for dir in `ls $SOURCE | sort -n`
do

  # define destination subdir
  dst_dir=$(( (($dir/50000) + 1) * 50000 ))

  # check if destination subdir exists
  if [ ! -d $DEST/$dst_dir ]
  then
    mkdir $DEST/$dst_dir
  fi 

  mv $SOURCE/$dir $DEST/$dst_dir

done
```

Comment: one correction here, to move $dir we should be inside $SOURCE dir or need to have absolute path else will get "no such file or directory"

Comment: it should be mv $SOURCE/$dir :)

Comment: Sorry, I hurried :) fixed again.

Comment: @NitinMestry May I interested why you change right answer? Answer from Hauke Laging looks very good.

Comment: to be honest its not about good looks, for me execution time and same level accuracy matters. your script take 7.05 mins which loops and perform operation on each dir. In Hauke Laging - execution time is just 4.32 mins due to use of array. I am from java and have achieved the same in java code before coming to this stack. Thanks you :)

Comment: In "looks good" term I mean approach too. Sorry for confuse. I've just been awarded that your chose about right answer changed several times. :) P.S. I write this script in several minutes and no thinking about effective work because I not see that is needed from the question. :)

Answer (score 1):

The math is somewhat tricky. A simple integer division `(file/50000+1)*50000` will fail. If the file number is 50000 the result is 100000. Not what you want. We need a shift of origin:

```
$(( ((file-1)/50000+1)*50000 ))
```

Also, a simpler code scheme is ok:

```
#!/bin/bash
fsource=/opt/dms;    fdest=/opt/nes_dms;    istep=50000
cd "$fsource"
for f In *; do
    i=$(( 1+(f-1)/istep ))              # Which bucket?
    fd="$fdest/$(( istep*i ))"
    echo  \
    mv -t "$fd" "$f"
done
```

Adding a couple of checks [(is a directory?) And (only digits)]:

```
#!/bin/bash
fsource=/opt/dms/;     fdest=/opt/nes_dms;     istep=50000
for f in "$fsource"/*; do
    [[ -d $f ]] || continue           # Is a dir?
    i=${f##*/}                        # Remove path.                                                  
    [[ $i =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] || continue  # Only digits?                                                  
    i=$((1+(i-1)/istep))              # Which bucket?
    fd="$fdest/$(( istep*i ))"
    echo  \
                       mv -t "$fd" "$f"
done
```

Comment out the echo when you are happy with the values and you want to execute the moves.